# Как продолжить анимацию квадрата JavaScript

Tags: javascript, анимация

Подскажите, 
как сделать, чтобы красный квадрат сделал круг по зеленому квадрату, 
то есть он проехал влево - вниз - вправо и вернулся откуда и начинал.

```js
function start() {
  var pos = 0;
  var box = document.getElementById("box");
  var t = setInterval(move, 1);

  function move() {
    if (pos == 150) {
      clearInterval(t);
    } else {
      pos++;
      box.style.left = pos + "px";
    }
  }

}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="start()">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function start() {
  var box = document.getElementById("box");
  var t = setInterval(move, 1);

  let direction = 0;
  let length = 150;
  let i = 0;
  let x = 0;
  let y = 0;

  const circleGen = (function* circle(){
      while(true){
          switch (direction){
              case 0:x++;break;
              case 1:y++;break;
              case 2:x--;break;
              case 3:y--;break;
          }
          i++;
          if(i === length){
              i = 0;
              direction++;
              if(direction>3) direction=0;
          }
          yield {x, y};
      }
  })();

  function move() {
    const point = circleGen.next().value;
    box.style.left = point.x + "px";
    box.style.top = point.y + "px";
  }

}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="start()">
```

Comment: Мне нравиться баг, который возникает, если нажать насколько раз на кнопку старт.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin да, очень круто! Напоминает спецэффекты некоторых фильмов ужасов!

Answer (score 5):

Для анимации лучше всего использовать анимацию, основанную на *CSS*.

Это лучше для:

- Производительности.
- Легкости кода.
- Дальнейшей расширяемости. Например, захотим добавить плавное изменение цвета.

Почитать про анимацию можно [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Ispolzovanie_CSS_animatciy).

```js
function start() {
  box.classList.add('animate');
}

function stop() {
  box.classList.remove('animate');
}
box.addEventListener("animationend", function(e) {
  e.target.classList.remove('animate');
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}

.animate {
  animation: move 6s ease;
}

@keyframes move {
  from {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  25% {
    left: calc(100% - 50px);
    top: 0;
  }
  50% {
    left: calc(100% - 50px);
    top: calc(100% - 50px);
  }
  75% {
    left: 0;
    top: calc(100% - 50px);
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="start()">
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stop()">
```

Comment: Капитан Очевидность, перелогиньтесь :) +1

Comment: @yar85 готово! Так лучше?)

Comment: Намного лучше! И изначальная формулировка тоже была хороша (тот случай, когда двусмысленность фразы не нарушает ее смысл, а делает емкой и остроумной).

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно для анимации использовать `css-animation`, а кнопкой старт сделать значение для свойства `animation-play-state`.

```js
function start() {
  document.getElementById('box').style.webkitAnimationPlayState = 'running';
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes square {
  0% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0
  }
  25% {
    top: 0;
    left: 75%;
  }
  50% {
    top: 75%;
    left: 75%;
  }
  75% {
    top: 75%;
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
}

#box {
  animation-name: square;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="start()">
```