# Обработчик события окончание анимации. JS и CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html5, css-animation

Нужно сделать анимацию. Чтобы элемент передвигался в одно место, затем в другое, потом в третье и т.п. То есть окончание одной анимации должно вызывать другую. Есть код:

```
photo_items[3].addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
    if (this.style.left === '234px') {
        this.style.left   = '39px';
    }
    if (this.style.left === '450px'){
        this.style.left   = '234px';
    }
});
```

По задумке, находясь на left = 450, он плавно переходит на left = 234, а затем на left = 39. Но по факту сразу переходит в left = 39.

Comment: Приложите к вопросу CSS и HTML, чтоб можно было наглядно покрутить в руках ([mcve])

Comment: А почему на js? я тебе такое на css могу написать без js. Просто уточни если нужно

Comment: дело в том что javascript сразу применяет стиль left 39 как только переходит на left = 234, никакой анимации при этом не будет.

Comment: Действительно, такие вещи лучше делать через `animation` а не через `transition`. Можете посмотреть мой ответ по анимации здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/814928/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-javascript/814938#814938

Comment: Есть ивент который можно отлавливать как и любое событие `animationend` примеры использования можно тут посмотреть https://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/

Comment: Чем лучше animationend от transitionend?

Answer (score 2):

Я так понимаю вам нужно что-то по типу этого:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 180px;
  position: relative;
}

.elem {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  animation: runSircle 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes runSircle {
    0% {left: 0; top: 0;}
    25% {left: 130px; top: 0;}
    50% {left: 130px; top: 110px;}
    75% {left: 0; top: 110px;}
    100% {left: 0; top: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='elem'></div>
</div>
```

Или [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/71btL88h/)

Comment: Нужно, чтобы была возможность менять время анимации. Поэтому важно переходить именно по окончании предыдущей анимации

Comment: Тогда нужно только на js это делать.

Comment: В этом и вопрос. Как это сделать в js?

Comment: Точно так же:) делаешь таймауты и по истечению указываешь новую точку. Принцып действия как анимация но через transition:)